# How to turn off on-premise kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have to move all nodes of kubernetes cluster(On-premise) physically for some reasons. So I should turn off them before moving. But I don't know how to turn off kubernetes cluster. Because Some pods are in there. So I thought out this procedure.

1. Backup etcd
2. [Scale down all pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64133011/scale-down-kubernetes-deployments-to-0-and-scale-back-to-original-number-of-repl)(replicas=0)
3. Turn off nodes
4. Move nodes
5. Turn on nodes
6. Restore etcd
7. Scale up all pods

Is this correct way to move kubernetes cluster nodes?

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no shutdown playbook for k8s cluster. For sure it's a different pattern for each individual, but there are common tasks that can be automated via a playbook, which can be executed after containers are drained.

For more details, refer to the  kubernetes [discussion](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/how-to-shut-down-and-restart-kubernetes-clusters/5395/6) blog.  There is no official playbook for shutting down K8s clusters.

The steps which you are following are correct, but it takes too much downtime and involves multiple config changes at the backend. So, instead of migrating your existing nodes to a new server try to create another cluster and migrate your application or pods to the new cluster as mentioned in this [blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/migrating-applications-between-kubernetes-clusters-8455cf1bfccd) by Luca Prete.